# How to migrate from WebApiConfig to Startup class (.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to Migrate a big project from **ASP.Net Framework** to **ASP.NetCore**. It's my first time doing this.

I've been researching for my own and I saw the steps more or less. [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.2), [A Step-by-Step Guide](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-migrate-project-from-aspnet-mvc-to-aspnet-core-qt1ks31zn).

The first trouble that I've found is migrating from `Global.asax`, `WebApiConfig`...  to `Startup.cs`.

This is my **WebApiConfig**:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        if (config != null)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 "DefaultApi",
                 "api/{controller}/{id}",
                 new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
                );

            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(ServiceBootStrapper.BootStrapper.Container);
            var logger = (ILog)config.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(ILog));
            config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new GlobalExceptionLogger(logger));
        }

        config.InitializeCustomWebHooks();
        config.InitializeCustomWebHooksSqlStorage();
        config.InitializeCustomWebHooksApis();
    }       
}
```

I know when you migrate to .net core, you can use 
`public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` for add Depencency Inyection and services.
and also you can use `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` for middleware, custom middleware...etc

So, first aproach of my startup:

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);       
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }


        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

But i don't know how continue. 
I have serveral questions

what can I do with?

- `config.InitializeCustomWebHooksSqlStorage()`
- `config.InitializeCustomsWebHooks()`
- `config.InitializeCustomWebHooksApis()`

Have I to add Custom middleware?

what about `config.DepencencyResolver`? Can I use native `Depency Inyection` or I have to use `Autofac`?

I'm really lost with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

you can add all the configuration in the configure method

Comment: I think that IConfiguration is for load appsettings.json  and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

For Autofac integration, read [this](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html).

As for webhooks, [I don't think there is ASP.NET Core replacements yet](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10898), unless someone could find otherwise.

Depends on what those webhooks actually do in your WebAPI application, you could implement equivalent middlewares to replace them.

BTW, your *Startup.cs* does not look as modern as ASP.NET Core 3. Take a look at [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-startup-class) for generic hosting in the latest ASP.NET Core version.